# how to get remote updates to my local working copy in git

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-flow

how do i update my local working copy of source code with current latest version of remote code?

This is the situation:

Suppose 2 people(`A,B,C`) are working on the project and they follows `git flow`..

There is `master` branch, and there is `develop` branch...everybody is pushing their updates to `develop` branch only..

Now `A` creates a feature branch (`featureA`) and does a commit and pushes it to remote..
`B` creates a feature branch(`featureB`) and commits and pushes it to remote..
`A`, and `B` continues their work in their remote branch...
while `C` created a new feature branch(`featureC`) and completed it and finished the feature and merged it to `develop`

So how can A and B update their local code to get the work done by person-C?

Should a normal `PULL` will solve the issue?

Or should they specifically pull to the current feature branch?
will `VS-code` automatically update the files after the `PULL`?

Or is some other combination of `git` commands?

Can some git expert please solve this dilemma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the commands (we states that **User C** merged into `develop` and pushed it).

**User A** and/or **User B** must:

```bash
git checkout feature/A # Obvious!
git fetch origin/develop
git merge develop
```

Or, if you want to review **User C** changes, so avoiding auto merge-commit, you should:

```bash
git checkout feature/A # Obvious!
git fetch origin/develop
git merge develop --no-commit

git diff

# ... review changes: accept or discard some of them ...

git commit # The commit message has been auto generated by the merge command
```

Comment: suppose there is a user D, and he has created a feature branch named (feature-D)... and he made a commit...but he didnt finish that feature, he didnt merge it to develop.. then how can userA and userB and userC get his work into their current working copy of source code? @Antonio Petricca

Comment: thanks @Antonio Petricca for your help... really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to realize that *branches*—or more precisely, branch *names*—don't really matter.  All that matter are the *commits*.  But there are two problems:

1. We (humans) *use* branch names to *find* the commits.
2. Branch names are specific to each Git clone.

What I mean by item 2 here is straightforward: if you and I both clone some repository (e.g., https://github.com/git/git), you get a `master` or `main`, and I get a `master` or `main`.  But in fact, if you go look at https://github.com/git/git/branches you will see that *they* have *six* branch names: `master` and `main` (which are essentially the same thing: the Git project is just very traditional here so they are keeping the old name from 2005 around for the next 100 years), plus (in alphabetical order) `maint`, `next`, `seen`, and `todo`.

Now, why is it that if they have *six* names, we only get *one* when we run `git clone`?  The answer is simple: because *our* branch names are *ours*, not theirs.  Our `git clone` *creates just one branch name* in our new clone.  If our `git clone` did not create a new branch name, we would have no branches at all!  Zero, zip, zilch, `0`, none.  Technically we don't actually *need any branch names*.  The only reason we might want a branch name in the first place is if we want to make a *new* commit.  Our new commit(s) need name(s) by which we can *find them*.  Git itself uses commit hash IDs—those big ugly strings of letters and digits like [<sup><sub>`30cc8d0f147546d4dd77bf497f4dec51e7265bd8`</sub></sup>](https://github.com/git/git/commit/30cc8d0f147546d4dd77bf497f4dec51e7265bd8)—to find the commits.  Git gives *us* names, such as branch names, tag names, and remote-tracking names, so that we (humans) aren't forced to memorize hash IDs.

You have actually asked two different questions here, probably without realizing it:

> 1. how [do I] get remote updates?

and:

> 2. how do i update my local working copy of source code with current latest version of remote code?

The answer to question 1 is much simpler: you use `git fetch`.  I'll put off question 2 for a separate section below.

The `git fetch` command needs one argument or parameter: *where should it go to get commits?*  We normally use what Git calls a *remote* to do this:

```
git fetch origin
```

means *Look up the name `origin`.  You will find a stored URL.  Use the stored URL to call up some other Git software and connect to some other Git repository.  Have them list out **their** branch names and other names and all the commit hash IDs associated with these names.  Using the hash IDs, bring over into **my** repository any commits they have that I don't have.  Then ...* (we'll come back to the *then* part in a moment).

The process of fetching commits works based on the *hash IDs*.  Every commit has a *unique* hash ID.  When you make a new commit, it gets a *new number<sup>1</sup> that has never been used before*.  That "uses up" the hash ID that you get: no other Git software, anywhere, in *any* repository, can use *that* number ever again,<sup>2</sup> *unless* it is to mark *that particular commit*.  That's how Git repositories share commits: the same *commit* has the same *number*.  That's really all there is to the sharing part: somehow, magically, Git can assign a unique number as a hash ID for a unique commit, and *every Git implementation agrees that that's the **right** number*.

So: you run `git fetch origin`, your Git reaches out to some other Git over at `origin`, and you get their commits.  Now you have *their* commits—and now you need some kind of *name* to remember the hash IDs.  This is where *remote-tracking names* come in.<sup>3</sup>  Your own Git software takes each of their *branch* names and changes them into *remote-tracking names*.  If I run `git branch -r` in my clone of the Git repository for Git, I get:

```
$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/main
  origin/maint
  origin/master
  origin/next
  origin/seen
  origin/todo
```

That's one *remote-tracking* name for each of their *branch* names, plus the special "symbolic ref" `origin/HEAD`, which I'll just ignore here.

My Git software, on running `git fetch origin`, will obtain from their Git all of their new commits—I already have all of their *old* commits—and will update my remote-tracking names so that my names remember *their* **branch** names and commit hash IDs.  So my remote-tracking names work, for me, somewhat like their *branch* names work for them.<sup>4</sup>

Once you've (successfully) run `git fetch`, using the *remote*—`origin` or `bob` or `boris` or whatever name you choose to store the URL for "their Git"—you have their commits, found in *your* clone via `origin/main` or `bob/main` or `boris/main` or whatever.

---

<sup>1</sup>While hash IDs have letters in them as well as digits, they're really just very large numbers expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).

<sup>2</sup>[This is technically impossible to maintain forever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), and someday Git will break, but the sheer size of the hash ID puts that day very far in the future (we hope), and other things help out as well (we hope).

<sup>3</sup>Git documentation calls these *remote-tracking branch names*, but the word *branch* in there is not doing much if any good, and is doing some damage.  Using the shorter phrase is, in my opinion, an improvement.

<sup>4</sup>This is why Git sticks that extra word *branch* in there.  But they *don't* actually work like *branch* names for me, which is one reason I say to leave that extra word out.  They only do *one* of the things that branch names do, and tag and other names do that too.  Why not just call these "remote-tracking names"?  (We could call them "reflections" or something, but I worry that that's getting too far away from existing Git terminology.  But this is what they are: they "reflect" (or "mirror") the names that my Git saw in *their* Git, the last time my Git called up their Git.)

---

#### "Checking out" vs "merging"

Let's visit your second question now:

> 2. how do i update my local working copy of source code with current latest version of remote code?

The word *update* is doing some heavy lifting here.  What, precisely, do you mean by *update?*

Git stores *commits*.  Each commit, besides being found by its hash ID, stores two things: *a full snapshot of every file*, like an archive (tar or WinRAR or zip or whatever), plus some *metadata*.  The metadata give you information about the commit itself: who made it, when, and so on, for instance.  The *snapshot* gives you a permanent archive of all the files.  Both parts are 100% read-only—no part of any existing commit can ever be changed<sup>5</sup>—and you can discard your *current* checkout at any time, if you wish, and replace it with any other commit.

If you just want to do that, you first need to discard or commit any work you've done that you have not yet committed.  This is because the working area—the place where you do your work, where files are *ordinary read/write files* that live in ordinary folders that your computer can work with—is *not in the repository.*<sup>6</sup>  You're about to tell Git to *overwrite* it, to rip out all the files from *this* commit and to go use a *different commit*.

Then, once `git status` says `nothing to commit, working tree clean`, you're ready to switch to some other commit.  Simply give `git switch --detach` the name or raw hash ID of the commit you want to view:

```
git switch --detach boris/branch-a
```

and now you have *that commit* in your working tree.

Note that you don't have a *branch*.  You are now in *detached HEAD* mode, where you can *look at* and *use* the commit.  You can even make new commits, but if you do so, Git isn't *saving the hash ID in a branch name*.  If you plan to make new commits, it's probably wise to create a new branch name now:

```
git switch -c newbr
```

and now you're on your own branch, named `newbr`, using this *same commit*.  (Multiple names—branch names, tag names, remote-tracking names, and so on—can all select *the same commit*, and this is the case now: both the remote-tracking name *and* the branch name `newbr` select this commit.)

But: **What if you don't want to just *use* their commit, but rather *combine* their commit's files with your own files?**  In this case, you probably want `git merge`, or perhaps some other action such as `git rebase`.  These kinds of commands are useful for *combining work*.

The choice of command *for* combining work is up to you.  Different people like to use different methods.  You must choose which method you want, and then learn which Git commands implement that method.  This leads us to your last Git question:

> 3. Should a normal PULL will solve the issue?

---

<sup>5</sup>This is required for Git's magic unique-numbering trick to work.  If you use the hash ID of some commit to *extract* the commit, then *make any change at all*, to the snapshot or metadata, and write the result back, what you get is a *new commit with a new and different hash ID*.  The old commit continues to exist.  So you literally can't change a commit.  Not even Git can do that.  Any *change* results in a different object.

<sup>6</sup>The "repository proper" is in the `.git` directory.  This is where Git stores its databases and ancillary files.  The area in which you do your work, called the *working tree* or *work-tree*, is not in the `.git` directory.  Instead, in a sort of inversion, the `.git` directory is normally a hidden folder in the top level of the working tree.  *Be careful not to wreck the contents of this `.git` folder* as your OS doesn't know how to coordinate closely with Git: you must use *Git commands* to update things in the `.git` folder, unless you know exactly what you're doing.

For the same reason, never put the `.git` folder in a cloud-synchronized storage area: most cloud-sync software *doesn't* cooperate with Git (I don't know of any that does, though having some do it would certainly be technically possible).  Software that assumes that files within `.git` are used by *humans* will mess with Git, which is not a human.

---

#### About `git pull`: don't use it yet

What `git pull` means is:

1. run `git fetch`; then
2. run a second command to do something using the fetched commits.

The *second* command that `git pull` runs is usually `git merge`, *unless* you tell Git that it should be `git rebase`.

The precise *way* that `git pull` runs this second command is complicated.  Since you're not sure yet which second command you want in the first place, don't drive a boat a few kilometers out to sea and then dive in without a life-jacket by running `git pull`.  First learn to swim in shallow fresh and salt water (run the individual commands and experiment with their behaviors), *then* learn to drive a boat (learn the `git pull` command itself) and try scuba diving or whatever.  The `pull` command has a lot of bad behaviors that exist because it was one of the earliest Git commands ever and was written before *remotes* (like `origin`) even existed.  It therefore encodes a whole bunch of *bad ideas*, that it continues to support for the same kind of reason that the Git project still uses the name `master`.

(A bunch of *defaults* have changed since I started with Git 1.5 or so, and it is a lot better now than it was then.  But it's still messy.  Learn from others' mistakes: start with `git fetch`, `git merge`, and `git rebase`.)

Comment: thank you very much @torek for giving such a detailed explanation.. i really appreciate you deciding to spend this much time to help me...

Comment: suppose there is a user D, and he has created a feature branch named (feature-D)... and he made a commit...but he didnt finish that feature, he didnt merge it to develop.. then how can userA and userB and userC get his work into their current working copy of source code?.. when i pull and merge code will VS-code automatically update the already open project file contents?

Comment: As above: run `git fetch` using a remote that will connect to a repository in which user D made his commit, or to which he has delivered his commit (either suffices). You now have his commit. Find it (by remote-tracking name or hash ID) and use it or incorporate it as you see fit.

Comment: (I cannot answer questions about VSCode. Note that VSCode is not Git, and has numerous plug-ins, each of which work differently, and some of which conflict. Ask VSCode questions in a VSCode forum.)